# Saving multiple .txt Files with a for Loop

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Problem with my saving Loop of my .txt-Files. It always saves the last File twice (if I put in `2 for the for loop`)

Currently I tried using `int writingLength = fc.getSelectedFiles().length;`, which then results in
no saving Option in total. Appreciate any thought that could help me to solve my problem, since I'm fairly new to Java.
Here the whole code snipped to give a better overview of my code:

```
    private void prepareTDDExcelDoc() {
        fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fc.resetChoosableFileFilters();
        fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        final FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel document (*.csv)", "csv");
        fc.setFileFilter(filter);
        int writingLength = fc.getSelectedFiles().length;
        for(int i=0;i<writingLength;i++) {
            final String suggestedFilename = reportName.replaceAll("\\W+", "_") + ".xlsx";
            fc.setSelectedFile(new File(suggestedFilename));
            final int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(frmCognosTddBuilder);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                    enableUserInteraction(false);
                    outputFilename = fc.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath();
                    final ExportedOutputInterface exportedExcelOutput = new ExcelOutput(this, outputFilename);
                    
                    progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor(getFrame(), "Builing TDD", "", 0, 100);
                    
                    task = new ReportDataExtracter(this, exportedExcelOutput);
                    task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                            if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
                                final int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
                                progressMonitor.setProgress(progress);
                                final String message = String.format("Completed %d%%.\n", progress);
                                progressMonitor.setNote(message);
                                if (progressMonitor.isCanceled() || task.isDone()) {
                                    if (progressMonitor.isCanceled()) {
                                        task.cancel(true);
                                    } else {
                                        progressMonitor.close();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    task.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why do you access `fc.getSelectedFiles().length` when the remainder of your code never uses `fc.getSelectedFiles()` ? It seems that you are calling this method with a list of pre-selected files in your filechooser. But then, why do you call `fc.showSaveDialog()` again, if you already have a list of files to work with?

Comment: @ThomasKläger I call `fc.getSelectedFiles()` in my loading Function, here I use it sole for the purpose of knowing how often my `for` Loop needs to run. Isn't `fc.showSaveDialog()` needed to save the files or is there another Way to save all the files without the Dialog? I'm calling 430 .txt Files currently with my filechooser and after I worked with them, need to save all 430 .txt files again as Exel files

Comment: `fc.showSaveDialog()` does not save the file. It allows the user to enter a new file name or select an existing file for overwriting. The actual saving is probably done in `task.execute();`. But if you use the same filechooser for the user to select a new output file name you loose the previously selected list of files.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Okay so I tried to use a new filechooser and now it can save multiple files. Basically, if I choose two files, I also save two files. It turns out that they are the same thought still. Could this be due to my code on how I read the files in? If that is the case than I might need to question my read in process again.

Comment: Yes, that could be. To process multiple files you have basically two options: read the first file, process it and save it, then read the second file, process it and save it and repeat these steps for all the other files. The other option is to read all files in parallel, process them in parallel and save them in parallel. This second approach means that you need to have a data structure for each file that contains the data of that file.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Okay second approach sounds a bit too much for me as a beginner currently, so I guess for now I will process them and save them before reading the second one in, thanks for the help! Much appreciated :)

Comment: @ThomasKläger opened another Thread about my read-in of files. Guess that is the Cause of my Problem, which I couldn't find the problem in yet. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67352293/how-to-read-multiple-txt-files-in-java)

Comment: It would have been better to add the code of the `importXMLEventHandler()` method to this question. Anyway: your `importXMLEventHandler()` already loops over the list of files to process. So this `prepareTDDExcelDoc()` just needs to process a single file and save the result into an excel file. You don't need a second (nested) loop in `prepareTDDExcelDoc()`, just a way to indicate the name of the currently processed file to the user. For this you could pass the `file` object from the `importXMLEventHandler()` into this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this "reportName" variable, which doesn't appear to be declared in this function, so I suppose it's an instance variable.  In any case, you're doing a small transformation on that value and setting it as the output file name for ALL the entries of the list.  I imagine the output file is only ever going to have the last file in the list.

It's really helpful to execute code like this in the debugger, so you can step through it and watch the values of variables.  As your code is creating UI components, you'll probably need to use two displays. It's been a few years since I had to debug UI code.

Comment: I tried debugging and normally that's the first thing I do, but I come from C++ and I'm fairly new to Eclipse. The Debug in here is quite diffrent and I still lose overview about my variables alot. Will try if I can find the Problem, thanks tho! :)